# Replacing SSL files and compiling NET :: ERR_CERT_DATE_INVALID

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian) I have updated SSL. I have replaced * .crt, * .key and * .pem files. My file configuration: ssl.conf:

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/m.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/m.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/m.ca.pem
```

At modelisa[com]pl I have an error opening the page. The upgrade involved replacing certificate files and restarting apache

Comment: Please edit your your post and rephrase as a question. I don't understand what you're asking. You mention an error message. What is that error message? Can you give us more background?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is saying the truth – the certificate is not *yet* valid for today's date.

Certificates don't just have an expiry date, they have a starting date as well. The latter is *usually* set to the moment of issuance, but for some reason your website's certificate has the following dates:

- Activation (notBefore): 2020-06-12 00:00:00 UTC
- Expiry (notAfter): 2021-06-12 00:00:00 UTC

This means you'll have to wait until Friday for the certificate to start working. (I have no idea *why* your CA would do this, but regardless, that's what they did.)

Comment: The author could in theory set their system date to after that time, but that is a ridiculous solution, I would just have the CA provide a correct certificate.

Comment: Well, that won't help for other visitors... Looks like OP has rolled back to the previous certificate (which _expires_ on the 12th, at 09:55) and I can only conclude that their CA has gotten renewal processing horribly wrong.